# HTML Canvas in for loop only displaying after loop completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm having a bit of trouble making a progress graph.  This is my first time using canvas so I'm a little new to the concept.  This page is going to be a little prime number benchmark for an assignment at school.  I haven't done the algorithm yet so right now that just counts up.  I wanted to have a graph display the progress of the benchmark to the user so it doesn't look like the page has just frozen.  I've broken the benchmark down into "sprints", where the device will calculate numbers for a set period of time and then update the graph.  Problem is, the graph doesn't seem to update until the end of the "benchmark".  Any recommendations?

The javascript is below (execBench is probably the most relevant function):

```js
function startBench() {
    // move to benchmark display
    //showPage("bench");
    jQuery.mobile.changePage("#bench");
    setTimeout(
        function () {
            // run benchmark
            var score = execBench(10);
            //set score and move page
            $(".result").text(score);
            setTimeout(function () {
                showPage("result");
            }, 4000);

        }, 2000);
}

function debugmsg(message) {
    console.log(message);
}

function execBench(time) {
    var graphUpdateRate = 2; // horizontal "resolution" of graph/sprint length in s
    var sprintCount = Math.floor(time / graphUpdateRate);
    debugmsg("Running " + sprintCount + " " + graphUpdateRate + "-second sprints");
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var sprintDeadline = currentTime;
    var counter = 0; // "score" for the end, # of primes generated
    var lastPrime = 0;
    var record = []; // datapoints for graph

    for (var i = 0; i < sprintCount; i++) {
        
        // perform calculations
        sprintDeadline = incrementDate(new Date(), graphUpdateRate);
        while (currentTime < sprintDeadline) {
            currentTime = Date.now();
            lastPrime = generatePrime(lastPrime);
            counter++;
        }

        // report progress
        record.push(counter);
        drawGraph(document.getElementById('progGraph'), record, sprintCount);
    }
    return counter;
}

function generatePrime(min) {
    //placeholder for algorithm
    min++;
    return min;
}

function drawGraph(canvas, dataPoints, maxPoints) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;
    var xIncrement = width / maxPoints;
    var xBegin = 0;
    var prevPoint = 0;
    var yScale = -1 * height / Math.max(...dataPoints);

    //reset canvas
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //move context to bottom right and set scale
    context.translate(0, height);
    context.scale(1, 1);

    context.strokeStyle = "#ed1e79";

    for (dataPoint in dataPoints) {
        currentPoint = (dataPoints[dataPoint] * yScale);

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(xBegin, prevPoint);
        context.lineTo(xBegin + xIncrement, currentPoint);
        context.lineWidth = 3;
        context.lineCap = 'round';
        context.stroke();

        prevPoint = currentPoint;
        xBegin += xIncrement;
    }

    debugmsg(Math.max(...dataPoints));
    return;
}

function incrementDate(date, seconds) {
    return new Date(date.getTime() + (seconds * 1000));
}
```

Comment: You are probably looking for requestAnimationFrame()

Comment: You need to use a scheduled update such as requestAnimationFrame() or setTimeout() to execute each iteration of drawGraph() so you don't block the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example of using requestAnimationFrame(), you could try something like this.

```js
function execBench(time) {
    var graphUpdateRate = 2; // horizontal "resolution" of graph/sprint length in s
    var sprintCount = Math.floor(time / graphUpdateRate);
    debugmsg("Running " + sprintCount + " " + graphUpdateRate + "-second sprints");
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var sprintDeadline = currentTime;
    var counter = 0; // "score" for the end, # of primes generated
    var lastPrime = 0;
    var record = []; // datapoints for graph

    var i = 0;
    (function drawSprint() {
    
        // perform calculations
        sprintDeadline = incrementDate(new Date(), graphUpdateRate);
        while (currentTime < sprintDeadline) {
            currentTime = Date.now();
            lastPrime = generatePrime(lastPrime);
            counter++;
        }

        // report progress
        record.push(counter);
        drawGraph(document.getElementById('progGraph'), record, sprintCount);
        
        i++;
        if (i < sprintCount) {
          requestAnimationFrame(drawSprint);
        }
    })();
    
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for getting the graph to update in realtime, thanks.  It had the side effect of making it move to the results page halfway through the benchmark but that's something I can fix.  Just to make sure I'm understanding correctly, is requestAnimationFrame recursively using that local "draw" function?

Comment: That's right. drawSprint() is executed one time, then uses requestAnimationFrame to request the browser call itself before the next repaint, which continues recursively until the sprints are done.

Answer (score -1):

Your `while` loop is "blocking". It eats up CPU, not allowing javascript and probably much else on the computer to do anything.

Instead, use `setTimeout(fn, t)` to schedule the next update.

`setTimeout()` is non blocking. Its `fn` will execute in a fresh event thread in t milliseonds time (or shortly thereafter).

Between setTimouts, your computer's processor will have the capacity to instruct the graphich card to render the canvas.

Comment: Downvoter, have the courage of your convictions. Explain what you think is wrong!